# Navigation bar issues - steps forming

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a problem with my navigation bar. When loading the page, sometimes it changes to look like its in steps however when you refresh it changes back to normal. I cant seem to find out what im doing wrong! Please help!!

Website is http://www.pearsonfoods.com.au

```
<div id="nav">
<a href="index.html" >
<div class="navBlock" style="color:red;"><p>Home</p>
</div>
</a>

<a href="about.html">
<div class="navBlock"><p>About us</p>
</div>
</a>

<a href="where.html">
<div class="navBlock"><p>Where we sell</p>
</div>
</a>

<a href="foods.html">
<div class="navBlock"><p>Our Foods</p>
</div>
</a>

<a href="contact.php">
<div class="navBlock"><p>Contact us</p>
</div>
</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is not well-formed. `<a>` is an "inline element" and `<div>` is a "block element". Block elements cannot exist within inline elements.

Your navigation list is better structured as a simple unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Where we sell</a></li>
</ul>
```

See? So much cleaner :)

Style each `<li><a>` as a block-flow element with `display: block;` (note this does not affect the inline/block semantics of elements, it's strictly a visual thing) and apply `float: left;` to the `<li>` elements.

Comment: do you know if there is anyway I can make the whole nav tab clickable for each page??

Comment: I'm looking at your updated website, and each tab is clickable. Have you fixed it recently since posting your comment?

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li> <a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
   <li> <a href="where.html">Where we sell</a></li>
   <li> <a href="foods.html">Our Foods</a></li>
   <li> <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>​
```

css

```
.nav {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav li {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    width: 180px;
    float:left;
}
.nav li a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    display:block;
}
.nav li a:hover,.nav li.current a{
    color:red;
}
```

[Link to running example](http://jsfiddle.net/HjDj3/)

Comment: No problem! I love it too ;)